# Loop and group by only when some conditions occur

Tags: sql, cursor

I have a trip that has sequence of stops

```
Trip  Stop  Time 
1     A     1:10
1     B     1:15
1     B     1:20
1     B     1:25
1     C     1:30
2     A     2:10
2     B     2:15
2     C     2:20
2     B     2:25
```

I want to transfer the table to:

```
Trip  Stop  Time  WaitTime
1     A     1:10   0
1     B     1:15   10min
1     C     1:30   0
2     A     2:10   0
2     B     2:15   0
2     C     2:20   0
2     B     2:25   0
```

I'm wondering if a oracle query can achieve it or cursor? 
pseudo code: 
SELECT case when previousstop = stop then time-lag(time) over (partition by trip order by trip,time) as waittime, but I don't know how to group by B.

FYI: In the second trip, I do wanna keep both Bs. The only time I want to group by B is when they are in sequence to each other. I don't think max, min will work well for this case.

Comment: This does not need a cursor, should it have the cursor tag?

Comment: Maybe what we really need is a DontUseACursorToDoThisEver tag.

Comment: If you think no cursor is needed ever, please en-light me with simple query.

Comment: vkp gives you the code to do it without a cursor in the answers.  His answer is good, use it.

Comment: I replied to vkp already. It won't work. If it's that simple I wouldn't come here. Thanks!

Comment: ok.  I can't do it with a simple query.  I still think a complex query would be better than a cursor.  You need to use framing (the over clause) or a recursive CTE.  Good luck.

Comment: just a side note on speed, using framing expected is `O(n)`, with recursive CTE `O(lg N)` and with a cursor `O(n^2)`

Comment: I do think a loop is better but I'm not quite familiar with cursor yet that's why I came here for help. I may handle this case with complex query but If there are other patterns occur I have to program it in. 2*2*2*...possibilities. I'm sure there are smart people here that can do it efficiently.

Comment: no idea what you mean by that, loop and cursor mean the same thing.

Comment: yeah I know a loop is cursor, but I'm not quite familiar with it yet I'm youtubing. Speed is not a concern right now, I need flexibility on the code for other patterns as well

Comment: does not matter how flexible your code is if it does not finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I figured it out myself! Here is the answer in case anyone needs

```
With TB AS (select t1.*
  ,sum(decode(t1.stop,t1.prev_stp,0,1)) over (partition by trip order by time) new_seq
from  
 (select t.*
        ,lag(stop) over (order by t.trip, t.time) prev_stp
  from   test t
  order  by tm) t1)

SELECT trip,stop,new_seq,min(etime) as Etime1, (max(etime)-min(etime)) wait time from TB 
group by trip,stop,new_seq
order by trip,new_seq
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with y as (select trip, stop, min(time) mintime, max(time) maxtime 
       from tablename group by trip, stop)
select y.trip, y.stop, y.mintime, (y.maxtime-y.mintime) waittime
 from y join tablename t 
  on t.trip = y.trip and t.stop = y.stop
```

Comment: It's not this simple, the query you are using may satisfied trip1, but for trip2 I wanna keep both Bs. If I extend trip 1 AS A,B,B,C,B, I want the result to be A,B,C,B. Max and min will lose the third B

Comment: got it..will try to get the solution you need

Comment: Appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works in SQL Server, assuming the time intervals are consistently 5 minutes.  I believe Oracle has equivalent functionality for everything here, but some syntax changes to make:

```
;with cte AS (
          SELECT   a.Trip
                  ,a.Stop
                  ,MIN(a.Time) AS Time                
                  ,x.Time AS EndTime                  
          FROM Table1 a
          OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 Time = a2.[Time]
                FROM Table1 a2
                WHERE  a.[Time] < a2.[Time]
                   AND a.[Stop] <> a2.[Stop]
                   AND a.[Trip] = a2.[Trip]
                ORDER BY a2.[Time]
               ) x
          GROUP BY a.Trip ,a.Stop, x.Time
          )
SELECT Trip,Stop,Time, WaitTime = COALESCE(DATEDIFF(minute,Time,EndTime)-5,0)
FROM cte
ORDER BY Trip,Time
;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36786/28/0)

If the time intervals are inconsistent, an extra step would be needed.

Comment: @SailorMoon  See updated, it's SQL Server syntax, but pretty sure there aren't too many changes needed for Oracle.

Comment: Appreciate I will try and come back. I came up with another solution, if a trip is A,B,B,B,C,B, I can name the stop sequence as 1,2,2,2,3,4, then I can Max/Min the query. But I haven't figure out how to row_number() partition it to that stop sequence yet with query. I know how to do it in C# >< Do you know how?

Comment: If you had a differentiator between first set of B's and 2nd B's then you just include that differentiator in your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @SailorMoon Oh I thought you had figured a way to make it '1,2,2,2,3,4`  where the second `B` could be differentiated.  The `OUTER APPLY` method is all I've got.